# Error trying to do a bootRun with Gradle - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle

I am trying to do a bootRun with Gradle - Spring MVC using eclipse but this error appears:

> ```
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip'.
> ```

That appears after the Server and JPA Hibernate seems to be load.

In the Console also appears this:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
> at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:154)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:272)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
> at palmaslab.mapas.config.Application.main(Application.java:71)
> :bootRun FAILED
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> BUILD FAILED
> Total time: 9.299 secs
> [sts] Build failed
> ```

This is my build.gradle file:

> ```
>   buildscript {
>     ext {
>         springBootVersion = '1.1.9.RELEASE'
>     }
>     repositories {
>         maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
>         mavenLocal()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.9.RELEASE")
>     }
> }
> apply plugin: 'java'
> apply plugin: 'eclipse'
> apply plugin: 'idea'
> apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
> apply plugin: 'war'
> apply plugin: 'jetty'
> apply plugin: 'application'
> sourceCompatibility = 1.7
> targetCompatibility = 1.7
> war {
>    version =  '0.1.0'
> }
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>     maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
>     maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }
>     flatDir {
>         dirs 'lib'
>     }
> }
> dependencies {
> compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
> compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:${springBootVersion}")
> compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
> compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${springBootVersion}")
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
> compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
>     compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc")
>  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.0.2.RELEASE")
>     compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.0.RC2")
>     compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2-javaconfig:1.0.0.M1")
> compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
> compile("com.h2database:h2")
> compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
>     compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2")
>     compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4")
>     compile("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0")
>     compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")
> compile("com.github.davidmarquis:fluent-interface-proxy:1.3.0")
>     compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.0.2.RELEASE")
>    compile ("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
>    compile ("commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1")
>     testCompile("junit:junit")
>     compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect") 
>     compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3")
>      compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
> def poiVersion = "3.10.1"
>     compile "org.apache.poi:poi:${poiVersion}"
>     compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:${poiVersion}"
>  compile "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1"
> }
> jar {
>     baseName = 'gs-uploading-files'
>     version =  '0.1.0'
> }
> task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
>     gradleVersion = '1.11'
> }
> ```

And this is my Application.java class:

> ```
>   @EntityScan(basePackages= "palmaslab.mapas.repository")
> @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= "palmaslab.mapas.repository"/*.PostoSaudeRepository.class*/)
> @Configuration
> @EnableAutoConfiguration
> @ComponentScan(basePackages="palmaslab.mapas.controller")
> @Import({palmaslab.mapas.security.SecurityConfiguration.class})
> @EnableWebMvc
> @PropertySource("application.properties")
> public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
> private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
>         "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
>         "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
>          }
>      @Bean
>         public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
>                 DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
>             LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
>             lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
>             lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
>             lef.setPackagesToScan("palmaslab.mapas.controller");
>             return lef;
>         }
> @Bean
>         public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
>             HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
>             hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
>             hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true); //Auto creating scheme when true
>             hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);//Database type
>             return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
>         }
> @Bean  
> public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() { 
>             SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
>             Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
>             dialects.add(new SpringSecurityDialect());
>             dialects.add(new LayoutDialect());
>             engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
>             LinkedHashSet<ITemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new LinkedHashSet<ITemplateResolver>(2);
>             templateResolvers.add(templateResolverServlet());
>             templateResolvers.add(layoutTemplateResolverServlet());
>             engine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
>             return engine;
>         }
> @Bean 
> public ServletContextTemplateResolver layoutTemplateResolverServlet() { 
>             ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
>             templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/layout/");
>             templateResolver.setSuffix("");
>             templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
>             templateResolver.setOrder(1);
>             templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
>             return templateResolver;
>         }
> @Bean 
>         public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolverServlet() { 
>             ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
>             templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
>             templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
>             templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
>         //    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
>             templateResolver.setOrder(2);
>             templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
>             return templateResolver;
>         }
> @Bean 
>         public ViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() { 
>             ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
>             resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
>             resolver.setOrder(1);
>             resolver.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
>             resolver.setCache(false);
>             return resolver;
>         }
> @Bean
>     public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {
>         ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
>         registration.addUrlMappings("/");
>         registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
>         return registration;
> }
> @Override
>     public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
>         configurer.enable();
>     }
> @Bean
>     public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
>         return new DispatcherServlet();
>     }
>     @Bean
>     public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
>         MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
>         factory.setMaxFileSize("999999KB");
>         factory.setMaxRequestSize("999999KB");
>         return factory.createMultipartConfig();
>     }
>      @Bean
>       public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
>         CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
>         resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000000);
>         return resolver;
>       }
> @Bean
>     public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
>         CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
>         resolver.setDefaultEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
>         resolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000);
>         resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(500000000);
>         return resolver;
>     }
>   @Bean
>     public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
>         TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
>         factory.setPort(8080);
>         factory.setSessionTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
>         //factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.404, "/notfound.html"));
>         return factory;
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
>         if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
>             registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
>                     "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
>         }
>         if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/locals/**")) {
>             registry.addResourceHandler("/locals/**").addResourceLocations(
>                      "classpath:/locals");
> }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a similar error message while running a Spring Boot application. Inside application folder i ran ./gradlew setMemDb bootRun.

The solution for me was to run,

- ./gradlew clean
- ./gradlew build

And then again the original command, ./gradlew setMemDb bootRun.

I'm guessing the reason for this problem would have been temporary files causing theses errors.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same issues once then found that profile is missing,

so below are the command to run application with profile, here we are using dev as profile

> SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev ./gradlew bootRun

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error, but the cause was something else. So I think it might be worth sharing:

My issue was I already had Tomcat running as a separate service, so I had to terminate that first.

FYI the command was: `sudo service tomcat8 stop`
Then I did a `./gradlew clean` and then `./gradlew bootRun`

Comment: Had the same issue and it was also due to the service already running. Killing Java processes solved the issue. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

whenever we run the project with bootrun it auto cleans and rebuild say you can just use the commend to run

```
./gradlew setMemDb bootRun
```

and hope it will not stop while running.

Answer (score 0):

I have to execute in root path of project

```
gradle clean
```

And

```
gradle build
```

Note: If for any reason in the build command, not works, delete the path node_modules and try again

Also update the gradle version to most recent version, can help us